# Python Sdk Code Example for Splittable Dofns in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating a dataflow pipeline in python in which i need to use FileIO because i want to access and keep track of the filenames processed.

Everything is working fine ,till my files are of small sizes. When running on a large files(GBS of data) , the dataflow job is not performant or scalable.

I have a solution of using splittable Pardos(dofns) which I have  earlier implemented using java, but now the preferred language is python.

The problem is that I am unable to find any decent code snippets (example) which will explain how to implement a splittable pardo (dofns) in python sdk.

I have found a code example in the beam documentation https://beam.apache.org/blog/splittable-do-fn/ , but it's not correct as far as I have tried it.

```
class CountFn(DoFn):
  def process(element, tracker=DoFn.RestrictionTrackerParam)
    for i in xrange(*tracker.current_restriction()):
      if not tracker.try_claim(i):
        return
      yield element[0], i

  def get_initial_restriction(element):
    return (0, element[1])
```

In this example , we are passing tracker=DoFn.RestrictionTrackerParam in the process method, but as I can see DoFn class does not have any parameter RestrictionTrackerParam.

As far as I have tested this example is not complete.

Can i get some help on getting a decent example of splittable dofns used in python sdk.

Comment: You can see this example with [Python](https://beam.apache.org/blog/splittable-do-fn-is-available/#:~:text=a%20splittable%20DoFn.-,Python%20Examples,-BoundedSourceWrapper%3A%20A%20wrapper)

Comment: If possible, can you please share the codeSnippit of the splittable DoFn that you had implemented in Java, I also have a pipeline that is using simple DoFN to read files using FileIO

Comment: @SaranshVashisth i reffered  the below links for Java implementation for splittable dofns: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dlp-dataflow-deidentification/blob/2136b1d7e32347618fac84bb2e7440c1377b3c14/src/main/java/com/google/swarm/tokenization/txt/TxtReaderSplitDoFn.java#L36   and     https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/571338b0cc96e2e80f23620fe86de5c92dffaccc/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/Read.java#L248

Comment: If you are using [Python](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/571338b0cc96e2e80f23620fe86de5c92dffaccc/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/iobase.py#L1375) yo can see this example or you can see this example in [java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/571338b0cc96e2e80f23620fe86de5c92dffaccc/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/Read.java#L248). I recommend using JAVA because it is the native language of Apache BEAM and it's faster than Python.

Comment: Thanks @RaulSaucedo  , but you have pointed to the source code which really doesn't help in any way.

Comment: I'm also looking for a complete working example of a Python-based SDF - specifically an unbounded one.